# Should we have more specific tags for the Witcher works?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am not a *The Witcher* expert, but as I understood there are some differences between the books and the show, also there is a very well-known game, [another TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hexer_(TV_series)) and so on.

Some of the questions could/should be about only one of them.

I know we have only one tag even for bigger universes, like [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) or [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) but there are a lot of complementary tags for them (characters, episodes, books, etc.)

The question is: **Should we have some tags for the different works? For example, something like [netflix-witcher](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netflix-witcher) or [geralt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geralt) or maybe even both?**

Comment: I don't see the need for it, as far as I'm aware the Netflix adaptation is very faithful to _The Last Wish_ which it is based off of.

Comment: If you want to restrict it to a specific medium you can always say so in the question and use the media tags to do so, i.e. [[tag:the-witcher]] [[tag:tv]]. That's how we do it for other works, [[tag:harry-potter]] being a good example of that I believe.

Comment: Title revision: Toss a coin...erhm... *tag* to your Witcher...

Answer (score 4):

### **One tag for the whole franchise: [the-witcher](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher).**

It's fine to define subtags as we've done in other franchises, but there should be one overarching tag so that someone who's interested in the whole franchise, everything Witcher related, can get all of that in a single list or by following a single tag. Also, many questions are going to be about the whole franchise without restricting to books, game, TV show, etc. If someone wants to know something about the Witcher lore, very often they won't care which part of the lore the answer comes from.

### **Media tags ...**

Our usual approach when a single story or franchise has been adapted for different media is to use media tags, for example [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv), [video-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games). In this case, things are complicated by the fact that, as you mention, there are two different TV series which are both in the same franchise but independent of each other. For [the 2002 one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hexer_(TV_series)) we could create a tag [the-hexer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hexer) (noting in the tag description that it's a subtag of [the-witcher](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher) and should always be used together with that), but for [the 2019 one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witcher_(TV_series)) it's a bit harder because the name of the TV series is the same as the name of the franchise. But maybe the tags [the-witcher](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher) [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) would be enough in this case (we seem to have had [no questions about *The Hexer* anyway](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=hexer+%5Bthe-witcher%5D)), less confusing than creating a new [the-witcher-netflix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-netflix) or [the-witcher-2019](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-2019) tag.

Comment: Yeah at the moment we don't really need any new tags creating, just use with a media tag if you want to restrict it.